# why is my jal getting +4 more than it should from pc?

Tags: mips

So my jal operator doesn't look like it's doing what it's suppose to do.  It looks like it is saving 4 addresses over what it's suppose to grab.  My test code is :

```
.data

test: .asciiz "test"
test1: .asciiz "test1"
test2: .asciiz "test2"
.text
main:
la $a0, test
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $t9, 5 # messing with line before jal
jal next
li $v0, 10 
syscall
# it should never hit this code
la $a0, test1
li $v0, 4
syscall
next:
la $a0, test2
li $v0, 4
syscall
jr $ra
li $a0, 1 # it should never hit this code
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

The output is: "Go: execution terminated with errors." The code isn't important, it's just suppose to show the problem with jal, does anyone know how to fix pc or jal? (I've reinstalled mars and java.)
[printscreenofjal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIrI3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you've enabled delayed branching in Mars' settings.

If you take a look at the description of `JAL` in *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set* you'll see that what you're describing is actually the correct and expected behaviour:

> Place the return address link in GPR 31. The return link is the address of **the second instruction following the branch**,
>   at which location execution continues after a procedure call.

This is because MIPS processors uses delayed branching, which causes the instruction immediately following the branch instruction to be executed before execution continues at the branch target. As a programmer this means that you have to take care of filling the branch delay slots, either by inserting NOPs after all branch instructions or by reorganizing the code.

Note that delayed branching is disabled by default, and if I run your program in Mars with delayed branching disabled I get the following output:

```
testtest2
-- program is finished running --
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I didn't know that was an option till you mentioned it.  I also thought reinstalling it would reset defaults.  Working now though.